# What's influence about and... why does it change randomly?

Tags: disgaea

I have been save-scumming myself greater counterattack in order to experiment with the effectiveness of bribes in the Assembly. However, at some point, I didn't have enough Influence to even start the vote. I thought I had loaded the wrong file, then I noticed...

[image: animated GIF of what is described in the post]

...the influence changes every time I select a character?!

What's influence, and why is it randomized?

Comment: Also, bribes: not at all very effective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The influence number corresponds to the sum of all the levels of the senators in the map. That's why it is never the same each time you select a character, as the number of senators in the Assembly and their levels are never the same, as it is randomized.

It does not have any incidence on the vote itself. It will only be helpful if you're going for the "Persuade by Force" option. The lower the influence number will be, the easier it will be for you to beat the senators and so to have the bills accepted.

Comment: ...so do I want to roll it as low as possible without having this number be so low that I cannot hold the vote?

Comment: Well, it will mainly be useful only if you want to use the "Persuade by Force" option. The lower the number will be, the easier it will be for you to beat them if you're not going for a vote. I modified the answer to add that information.